# get access to com.android.internal.telephony.Call

Tags: android, api, phone-call, internal

I need to get access to com.android.internal.telephony.Call.

doing so:

```
// Initialize the telephony framework
PhoneFactory.makeDefaultPhones (this);

// Get the default phone
Phone phone = PhoneFactory.getDefaultPhone ();

CallManager mCM = CallManager.getInstance ();
mCM.registerPhone (phone);

Call call = mCM.getFirstActiveBgCall();
```

but does not extend to initialize the framework.

Help me to initialize Call.

I need to read the state of the call like:
IDLE, ACTIVE, HOLDING, DIALING, ALERTING, INCOMING, WAITING, DISCONNECTED, DISCONNECTING.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make use of [PhoneStateListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/PhoneStateListener.html)
It will provide you the facility to have your application listen for different state of a phone call. You will need to put `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>` in your manifest file

Comment: PhoneStateListener can only listen on conditions such as IDLE, OFFHOOK, RINGING.

CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK - At least one call exists that is dialing, active, or on hold, and no calls are ringing or waiting.

I need to know about the moment when the call is answered.

CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK displays all the states together.

Answer (score 0):

You can but there is a critical requirement: the application must be signed at system level, meaning **you are the manufacturer**.

Here is how you write a Service that will broadcast an intent for every change in the foreground call state.

```
/*
 * This implementation uses the com.android.internal.telephony package: you have
 * to extract the framework classes .jar file from the platform (or the
 * emulator) to compile this code. Also, add the jar file to the external
 * libraries in the Java Build Path/libraries of the android project. </p>
 * 
 * The jar file must match the android version you are building the application
 * for. Because this implementation is using the internal packages it cannot be
 * guaranteed to operate on later versions of android.
 */
public class CallStateNotificationService extends Service {

    private static final String LOG_TAG = CallStateNotificationService.class.getSimpleName();

    private Handler mHandler = new Handler() {

        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.handleMessage(msg);

            if (msg.what == 101) {
                CallManager callManager = CallManager.getInstance();
                Call.State state = callManager.getActiveFgCallState();

                Intent intent = new Intent(PhoneIntents.ACTION_PRECISE_CALL_STATE);
                intent.putExtra(PhoneIntents.PRECISE_CALL_STATE, state.name());

                Context context = getApplicationContext();
                context.sendBroadcast(intent);
            }
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        try {
            CallManager callManager = CallManager.getInstance();
            if (callManager != null) {
                callManager.registerForPreciseCallStateChanged(mHandler, 101, null);
            } else {
                Log.w(LOG_TAG, "Can't resolve CallManager reference"); //$NON-NLS-1$
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

        CallManager callManager = CallManager.getInstance();
        if (callManager != null) {
            callManager.unregisterForPreciseCallStateChanged(mHandler);
        } else {
            Log.w(LOG_TAG, "Can't resolve CallManager reference"); //$NON-NLS-1$
        }
    }
```

And here is the definition of the custom broadcasted intents.

```
/** Intent action and extra argument names for CallStateNotificationService */
public final class PhoneIntents {

    public static final String ACTION_PRECISE_CALL_STATE = "com.myorg.myapp.CALL_STATE";

    public static final String PRECISE_CALL_STATE = "precise_call_state";
}
```

To have this code compile and link, you of course need to either build the program as part of the android distribution itself or import the class-framework by a method explained elsewhere on the Internet.

All of this is currently in an app under production.